# Where are @font-face files stored on the client side?

Tags: css, font-face

When you use the @font-face protocol, the client essentially downloads the font from the server. Where is this file stored on the client's computer? Is it stored on the physical drive or just in memory? How easy is it for the client to obtain the file?

Comment: I'd be interested to see if anyone knows an answer for certain but it seems like each browser (platform specific) would store them in temporary cache like the rest of the data cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is this file stored on the client's computer?

Wherever the browser wants (including, possibly, only in RAM).

> How easy is it for the client to obtain the file?

Trivial. They can read the URL from the CSS file and download it manually if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let's say that reading from the URL isn't an option. How easy would it be to extract the file from the cache?

Comment: fontsquirrel.com has an option when you generate a font called "WebOnly" in which the font is: `unusable as a system font, but fully functional as a webfont`. That quote is from Paul Irish: http://www.typophile.com/node/70404?page=1. Apparently you can just mess with the name of the font and Windows/MacOS won't read them but they can be used as web fonts.

Comment: In certain browsers, such as Chrome, you can see the font in the web developer resources window. You may be able to grab the fonts from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the may concern is how distribution of fonts work (copyright), since people will be able to download em (why? because fonts are remotely stored like any file in your server so they work as cache), making it an illegal distribution for those that don't have a free license, that's pretty much one of disadvantages of @font-face, how you could fix it? Well either encode our copyright fonts or keep using free distribution fonts.

Check this link you can read a little bit more about performance of @font-face like... how much does it take to load fonts, hope you find it helpful!

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/